# C#, WebService + прокси

Tags: c#

Всем привет. В своем проекте через Add Service Reference... добавил ссылку на веб сервис. После чего, Visual Studio сгенерировала мне соответствующий класс.

Все работает, данные с этого веб сервиса я получаю. Но, когда выход в инет осуществляется через прокси-сервер, вылетает exception суть которого заключается в том, что не указаны соответствующие настройки для прокси-сервера. Собственно сам вопрос, где и как эти настройки можно задать в этом сгенерированном Visual Studio  классе?

Comment: http://goo.gl/OHfau6

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!